# Node Scheduler Repetition

Tags: node.js

A friend and I are trying to use Node Scheduler to have a discord bot announce things on certain days (Essentially a holiday calendar). We want it to post one pre set message, but it seems to post the messages a random amount of times.

```
    var Hb = schedule.scheduleJob('* 6 14 20 4 *', function(){
bot.channels.get('435858985501982720').send('new message 3');
});
```

This is our tester code, does anyone know what's wrong?

Edit: we do want specific minutes, idk if that has any affect.

Comment: I recommend you to use https://crontab.guru/ for testing your `-cron` pattern before it becomes live. Also make sure that you cron task don't restart the bot itself.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `schedule.scheduleJob` is a string representing when the function should fire, **in cron format**. [According to the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule#cron-style-scheduling) you are trying to run the function:

- every second
- 6 minutes past the hour
- 14th hour (2pm)
- 20th day of the month
- 4th month (April)
- every day of the week

aka every second at 2:06pm on 20th April every year.

I would rewrite the cron string using the format the docs provided:

```
*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
```

e.g. to run at midday on Christmas every year:

```js
schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 12 25 12 *', function(){
     bot.channels.get('435858985501982720').send('new message 3');
});
```

Comment: i should've mentioned this, but we do want specific minutes. Does that have any affect on the repetition? It seems to still post multiple times even if seconds is set to 0.

Comment: @Fletchlingboy no? as the diagram mentions the second number is the specific minute past the hour. e.g: `5` for 5 minutes past the hour, `20,40` for 20 & 40 minutes past the hour, `*` for every minute of the hour. You can use to get a better understanding on *cron* you can look at https://crontab.guru/ **but this site is not 1:1 with node schedule syntax**. If you are still having problems with it you can describe when you want it to run and ill try and piece together the expression you want